# How do I a C# XUnit test using a [Theory] tag that takes static member methods as a parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, xunit

I'm working with XUnit in .Net/C#.
I have several classes which static methods with similar signatures.

**Consider the following class definitions:**

```
public class FooClass
{
    public static string Generate(SomeOtherClass p_class)
    {
    }
}

public class FooClass1
{
    public static string Generate(SomeOtherClass p_class)
    {
    }
}
```

I would like to write a single test which takes as a parameters:

```
FooClass.Generate(p_class);
FooClass1.Generate(p_class1);
```

**Given the following test method definition:**

```
[Theory]
public void TEST_Generate(??????)
{
}
```

How would I do set up my XUnit test method to use a [Theory] to accept multiple definitions of static class member methods?

Thanks,JohnB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData()
{
  Func<string> p1 = () => FooClass.Generate(new SomeOtherClass());
  yield return new object[] { p1 };
  Func<string> p2 = () => FooClass1.Generate(new SomeOtherClass());
  yield return new object[] { p2 };
}

[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(TestData))]
public void Test_Generate(Func<string> func)
{
  var result = func();
  Assert.Equal("expected", result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Exactly what I was looking for. JB